# The percentage of a number to zero

Tags: divisibility

let's imagine that a student got **0** marks in a exam. And in the next one he got **5** marks. to calculate the percentage of the new mark to the last mark, we usually use (new-last)/last*100%. but the denominator is **0**. So the expression should be (5-0)/0*100%, right? But **0** as denominator will result in error in calculator. So how to calculate?

Comment: "He scored" or "He got off the mark" might work, while "He did infinitely better" would be misleading.  Alternatively, don't divide and just say "he scored 5 marks (more)".

Comment: sorry can you be more specific?
is it possible to calculate a percentage of a number to zero

Comment: @AlexanderHo: No, this is not possible - there is no way to give a useful percentage value here. This is because there is no number $p$ such that $p \cdot 0 = 5$, so there is also no percentage.

Comment: Instead of measuring the percentage change in marks, an improvement rating out of $100$ could be given by $100(1-e^{\frac{new \ mark}{old \ mark}})$. Then as old mark $\to 0$, the rating $\to 1$, and the ratings of students who score low and improve slightly do not dwarf that of students who score fairly high then improve a lot.

Comment: @JohannesKloos Could you promote your comment to an answer so as to remove this question from the Unanswered queue? You could also incorporate the alternative method $100(1-\exp(-\frac{\text{new mark}}{\text{old mark}}))$ that Angela proposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not possible - there is no way to give a useful percentage value here. This is because there is no number $p$ such that $p\cdot0=5$, so there is also no percentage.

Alternatively, as Angela proposes, instead of measuring the percentage change in marks, an improvement rating out of $100$ could be given by $100(1−\exp(-\frac{\text{new mark}}{\text{old mark}}))$. Then as $\text{old mark}\to0$, the rating goes to $1$, and the ratings of students who score low and improve slightly do not dwarf those of students who score fairly high and subsequently improve a lot.